# Liferay document library API - help required for a beginner

Tags: api, liferay, document

I am completely new to Liferay and unfortunately have limited knowledge of portlet, liferay APIs etc. 
I have been asked to use liferay's document library API to add documents in one of our portlet.
We are using 5.2.3 version currently. I could find the javadocs which has methods like addFileEntry, addFile in classes such as DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil, DLLocalServiceUtil etc, but having a very hard time to understand which method to use or which class to use.

Also, most of these APIs takes parameters such as userId, groupId, companyId etc etc. From where can I get that?

I know I am asking some very basic questions and should first try to understand the key concepts behind liferay, but unfortunately have been given very limited time :(. My bad luck.

It would be really helpful, if anyone can provide some sample code base with some explanation on it or guide me to any link.

Thanks,
Ashish

Comment: have u done with our problem???then make it answer so it will help others...

Answer (score 3):

you can get userid,companyid,scope id from this method....

```java
ThemeDisplay td = (ThemeDisplay) renderRequest.getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);
long userId = td.getUserId();
```

like wise you can get companyid,scopeid and all..

To add documents you can use...

```java
DLFileEntry file=DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil.addFileEntry(userId,
               groupId,
               folderId,
               myfile.getName(),//name
               myfile.getName(),//title
               "",//description
               "",//changelog
               "",//extra seeting
               myfile,
               serviceContext);
```

Try this..

Answer (score 0):

This approach suggested by Lucky Boy will not check permissions. If you want that the permissions will be checked use `DLFileEntryServiceUtil` instead of `DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil`.

```java
DLFileEntry file=DLFileEntryServiceUtil.addFileEntry(
           folderId,
           myfile.getName(),//name
           myfile.getName(),//title
           "",//description
           "",//changelog
           "",//extra seeting
           myfile,
           serviceContext);
```